# We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email

Tags: magento2

I am getting below error in magento2 local system.

> We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email.

**Can anyone help me please**

Comment: What are you using in your local system? Is it DevBox? What are the steps you are doing that triggers the error? Anything in Magento logs?

Answer (score 1):

this is usual problem if you install the sample data (or even without sample data in many cases).

This may be due to some php-extension not installed properly, there are plenty of answers you can have a look at these.

[Magento 2 error: We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101492/magento-2-error-were-sorry-an-error-has-occurred-while-generating-this-email)

https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-2/1796-we-re-sorry-an-error-has-occurred-while-generating-this-email

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356517/magento2-error-were-sorry-an-error-has-occurred-while-generating-this-email/38933708