# magento 2- website showing: We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content

Tags: magento2, frontend, fatal-error

i haven't opened my website backend since two days and today when i went to frnt page www.xxxxxx.com it showed me a single line content

> We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content.

between header & footer content... i've cleared the caches, flushed magento cache but nothing changed any suggestions what should i do?
[image]

Comment: check this post hopefully it will help : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101492/magento-2-error-were-sorry-an-error-has-occurred-while-generating-this-email

Comment: @naveed that link is for email error.. and here i am getting content error

Comment: Yes i know, but the error message is generic and there multiple steps are given to diagnose / fix the issue, so it could be any of these reasons mentioned in above link

Comment: @Laiba How are you? Have you fix the issue please? I encounter the same issue here

Comment: Remove all content once from CMS page and check if it is working fine than something wrong in your content.

Comment: @HiteshKoshti - when we remove the content and just paste normal text it works. but if We add HTML it breaks and same error is shown